# Problem with VB code sending request to API to parse batch of user agents

Tags: vb.net, api, parsing, user-agent

Authenticating my API requests is done by sending an HTTP Header called: X-API-KEY with the value being my API Key which I got by following the Get your API Key instructions.

The UserAgentParseDataBatchRequest and UserAgentParseDataBatchResponse show BC30002:Type 'UserAgentParseDataBatchRequest' is not defined. The same shows for UserAgentParseDataBatchResponse.What do I need to do in order for this to work.

Module Program

```
Sub Main()

    Const API_KEY = "efebbbc7b3ec945e2890afc9143610e5"

    Dim userAgentsToParse = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    ' userAgentsToParse("1") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
    ' userAgentsToParse("2") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    ' userAgentsToParse("3") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12"
    ' userAgentsToParse("4") = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36"
    ' userAgentsToParse("5") = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
    ' userAgentsToParse("6") = "Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 5.55) AppleWebKit/601.2 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    ' userAgentsToParse("7") = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
    ' userAgentsToParse("8") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

    Dim apiUrl = "https://api.whatismybrowser.com/api/v2/user_agent_parse_batch"

    Dim headers As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    headers.Add("X-API-KEY", API_KEY)

    Dim postData As New UserAgentParseDataBatchRequest
    postData.UserAgents = userAgentsToParse
    'postData.ParseOptions = New UserAgentParseDataRequestParseOptions
    ' postData.ParseOptions.ReturnMetadataForUserAgent = True

    If (userAgentsToParse.Count > 500) Then
        Console.WriteLine("You are attempting to send more than the maximum number of user agents in one batch")
        Return
    End If

    Dim client = New RestClient(apiUrl)
    client.UseNewtonsoftJson()

    Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.Post)

    For Each header In headers
        request.AddHeader(header.Key, header.Value)
    Next

    request.AddJsonBody(postData)

    Dim result = client.Execute(request)

    Dim response As UserAgentParseDataBatchResponse
    Try

        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of UserAgentParseDataBatchResponse)(result.Content)
    Catch ex As Exception

        Console.WriteLine(result.Content)
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't decode the response as JSON: {0}", ex)
        Return
    End Try

    If (response.Result.Code <> "success") Then
        Console.WriteLine("This API did not return a 'success' response. It said: result code: {0}, message_code: {1}, message: {2}",
                          response.Result.Code, response.Result.MessageCode, response.Result.MessageCode)
        'Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented));
        Return

    End If
    ' Now you have "result_json" And can store, display Or process any part of the response.

    ' --Display some basic info about each parse result in the list
    For Each parseRecord In response.Parses

        ' -- get the whole result from the batch
        ' this includes the 'parse' dict, as well as 'result'

        If (parseRecord.Value Is Nothing Or parseRecord.Value.Result Is Nothing Or parseRecord.Value.Result.Code <> "success") Then
            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem parsing the user agent with the id {0}", parseRecord.Key)

            If (Not parseRecord.Value Is Nothing And Not parseRecord.Value.Result Is Nothing) Then
                Console.WriteLine(parseRecord.Value.Result.Message)
            End If

            Continue For
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parseRecord.Value, Formatting.Indented))

        Dim parse = parseRecord.Value.Parse

        Console.WriteLine("{0}: [{1}/{2}] {3}", parseRecord.Key, parse.HardwareType, parse.SoftwareType, parse.SimpleSoftwareString)
    Next

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Did you get this code from some code sample, in the API *manual*? Where are `UserAgentParseDataBatchRequest` & Co. defined? What SDK / NuGet Package are you using?

Comment: Yes and yes I didn't scroll down to the class definition until recently. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're missing the class definition for **UserAgentParseDataBatchRequest**.

You set postData to a new UserAgentParseDataBatchRequest and clearly "**Type 'UserAgentParseDataBatchRequest' is not defined**"

Based on postData though, we know the definition should have at least:
.UserAgents
.ParseOptions
.ParseOptions.ReturnMetadataForUserAgent

Comment: Yes. I didn't scroll down the manual code enough for the different class definitions. I have everything know but when I try to run it with visual studio, I get:

Comment: Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'TestApiAuth.WebForm1' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestApiAuth.WebForm1" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>